# add uuid for a node in neo4j graph db with php api

Tags: php, neo4j, neo4jphp

I am trying to assign a unique id to every node that i create. I tried the following syntax but failed can somebody point me in the right direction?

I want to mention that I am using Neo4jPHP Api.

```
 $test =  $this->client->makeNode();
        $test->setId(2212313131)

            ->setProperty('age', 12)

            ->save();
        $label = $this->client->makeLabel('test');
        $test->addLabels(array($label));`
```

Answer (score 1):

The id used by `setId()` is the internal Neo4j id for the entity. It cannot/should not be set manually (the method is only exposed so that the HTTP client can set it from responses.)

If you want to have your own ID for a node, make a property called `id` or `uuid` or whatever you want:

`$test =  new Node($client);
$test ->setProperty('uuid', 2212313131)
       ->setProperty('age', 12)
       ->save();`

Then use a label or Cypher to look up the node by property.